# Why am I getting an error: illegal start of expression public voidm1() { (in a short code)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

**Given:** Consider the following interface and class: What must be true about the code for class C in order for that code to compile successfully?

This is the code snippet our teacher gave us

```
    public interface I {
    public void m1();
    public void m2();
    }


    public class C implements I {
      // code for class C
    }
```

This is a very vague question. This is what I have tried so far, but I'm getting `illegal start of expression public void m1(){`

The code thus far:

```
     interface I {
    public void m1();
    public void m2();
}

public class C implements I {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        public void m1() {
            System.out.println("To be honest..");
        }
        public void m2() {
            System.out.println("It's a vague question to begin with.");
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    C why = new C();  
    why.m1();
    why.m2();
    }
}
```

How do I fix the error? I actually don't know how to arrange it properly..

(This has been solved now. Thank you. I really appreciate it)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can't nest methods inside other methods in Java, so I am not sure what you intended to do here?

Comment: Main method is twice? Even in C object and can't take nested method in java, what exactly you trying

Comment: (The background for this is the OP's previous question.  In the problem they are trying to solve is how to make the `C` class at the top compile.  The answers to that question say how, but the OP is off down a "rabbit hole" with overly complicated solutions including a totally unnecessary `main` method, and (now) putting the `m1` and `m2` methods in the wrong place.)

Comment: Ms Confused: my advice to you is to review your Java textbook or course notes and pay particular attention to the parts that talk about 1) the syntax of a class and its methods, and 2) how to implement methods in a class that were declared in an interface.  It you try to *guess* what the syntax needs to look like you will run into trouble.  If you try to randomly include stuff (like `main` methods) to see if it will help, you will get into trouble.  Go back to your reference material and read it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Nesting method definitions prohibited

You cannot define one named method within the definition of another named method.

So this:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args){
        public void m1() { …
```

… is illegal.

Your `main` method is a method — a very special method, but still a method. So move your `m1` method outside, elsewhere.

```java
package work.basil.demo;

// This class carries 3 methods, 1 special `main` method, and 2 regular methods.
public class C implements I
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Do stuff here… instantiate objects, call methods. But do not define a nested method." );
        C see = new C();
        see.m1();
        see.m2();
    }

    public void m1 ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "Running m1 method." );
    }

    public void m2 ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "Running m2 method." );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
Do stuff here… instantiate objects, call methods. But do not define a nested method.
Running m1 method.
```